# error MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(menuname) =('') where menuname=('Food Menu')'

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays, `$arr` for the old menu name, and `$arr1` for the new menu name. I want to replace the old menu name with the new in my database. I have the following code but it throws out an error.

```
<?php
$arr  = explode(',', preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/', '$1', trim($_POST['menuname'],
                                                                 '[]')));
$arr1 = explode(',', preg_replace('/^.*\
       [(.*)\].*$/', '$1', trim($_POST['editmainmenu'], '[]')));

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("test");
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $value1 = $arr1[$key];

    mysql_query("update test set (menuname) =('" .
                    mysql_real_escape_string($value1) . "') where menuname=('" .
                    mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')")or
        die('unable' . mysql_error());
    echo "updated";
}
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
04-09 19:06:27.201: I/System.out(1291): unableYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(menuname) =('') where menuname=('Food Menu')' at line 1
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code looks like after the cleanup I did to it:

```
<?php
$old_menu_names = explode(',',
                          preg_replace(
                              "|\[(.+)\]|",          //Find the part in between the square brackets
                              "$1",                  //And extract it
                              trim(
                                  $_POST['menuname'] //From the trimmed menuname.
                              )
                          )
);
$new_menu_names = explode(',',
                          preg_replace(
                              "|\[(.+)\]|",
                              "$1",
                              trim(
                                  $_POST['editmainmenu']
                              )
                          )
);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("test");
foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name)
{
    $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$key]);
    $old_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname = '$old_name'")
        or die('Error' . mysql_error());
    echo "Updated";
}
?>
```

##What I did:

- Variable naming - Name your variables according to what they contain, don't use obscure names such as `$arr` or `$arr1`, in larger applications, you'll be lost in no time.
- If a statement is long, complex, and/or contains nested brackets, don't be afraid to line break it so that it would be easier to follow.
- Comments, when something is not immediately understood, feel free to add comments explaining to anyone (including yourself in a few months) what the code is intended to do.
- Don't add brackets where they're not needed. See the new query I wrote.
- You didn't declare the old name inside your foreach loop, so that came out empty the threw an error.

In short, I suggest you read a good book about best practices and programming concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on the answer provided by Emil:

> Remove all unneeded parentheses.

You have incorrect and unnecessary parenthesis in your SQL statement. Your statement would look like this:

```
update test set (menuname) = ('foo') where menuname = ('foo2');
```

When it should look like this (Minus the incorrect parenthesis):

```
update test set menuname = 'foo' where menuname = 'foo2';
```

Also it would be much easier to read if you expressed the SQL statement in Capital Letters:

```
UPDATE test SET menuname = 'foo' WHERE menuname = 'foo2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all unneeded parentheses.

Comment: sir i think all parentheses are correct please tell me where can i remove

Comment: If this isn't the correct answer, if it didn't fix your problem, don't accept it as correct. You can remove the acceptance by click on the green V again (no offence to @Emil, it just seems as if it didn't solve his problem)